# PowerShell Get-Team Display Name from GroupID

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

Good afternoon all,

Would greatly appreciate your help and perhaps a little of your patience as i am very very new to Powershell.

I am trying to export a .csv list of MS Teams 'Owners' and their 'Team Names'. Whilst i have the team owners:

`$TeamOwner = (Get-TeamUser -GroupID TEAM_ID_HERE | Where-object {$_.Role -eq 'Owner'}.User`

I cannot seem to get the 'DisplayName' from the the GroupID. My latest attempt loos like:

`$TeamName = (Get-Team -GroupId TEAM_ID_HERE | select DisplayName).DisplayName` - but this is really a stab in the dark from multiple existing threads.

ANy help on returning a DisplayName from the GroupID would be most welcome.

Comment: Doesn't `(Get-Team -GroupId TEAM_ID_HERE).DisplayName` work?

Comment: I get the following error when i try the code above. 

`Get-Team : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'GroupId'.
At C:\Users\USER\TeamOwner.ps1:29 char:23
+ $TeamName = (Get-Team -GroupId TEAM_ID_HERE). ...
+                       ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Team], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Custom.GetTeam`

For clarity the -GroupID is the underlined parameter that cannot be found.

Comment: That is weird because it is described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/get-team?view=teams-ps).. Do you perhaps need to update the MicrosoftTeamsPowerShell module?

Comment: Hi Theo, thanks for you help looking into this. I've posted the broader question into a new Thread - apologies if this is poor etiquette. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72058588/powershell-team-owners-and-team-names-from-a-list-of-groupids)