# PowerShell Team Owners and Team names from a List of GroupIDs

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

Good afternoon all,

Hoping someone can help with a broad problem I'm having with efficiency in the follow PowerShell query.

In brief, the idea behind the following code is:

**1)**From a predefined list of MS Teams GroupID's (260+ in total), all held in 'List.txt' file

**2)**Run through each of the MS Teams GroupIDs and extract the **Team Name** and the **Team Owners**.

**3)**Export the data to a .csv in the format:

| Team Name: | Team Owners: |
| --- | --- |
| STH-TeamName | Owner1@nhs.net, Owner2@nhs.net |
| STH-AnotherTeam | Owner3@nhs.net, Owner4@nhs.net |

The code, whilst cobbled together from a number of sources does appear to be working in essence. However, "Write-Host" steps **2** and **5** appear to be returning the DisplayName very slowly indeed. I am a complete beginner with PowerShell queries so the syntax and general efficiencies are not in my favour at the moment.

```
Import-Module Microsoftteams

Connect-MicrosoftTeams

Write-Host 1 Opening Lists File...
$TeamList = Get-content C:\users\USERNAME\TeamOwnerReport\List.txt

Write-Host 2 Stepping Through Team GroupIDs...
$TeamIDs = Foreach ($Item in $TeamList)
{get-team | where-object {$_.GroupID -eq $Item}
}

Write-Host 3 Stepping AllTeams are TEAMIDs...
$AllTeams = $TeamIDs.GroupID 

Write-Host 4 Doing Array bit...
$TeamReport = @()

Foreach ($Team in $AllTeams)
{
Write-Host 5 Doing teamName bit...
$TeamName = (Get-Team | Where-object {$_.GroupID -eq $Team}).DisplayName

Write-Host 6 Doing teamOwner bit...
$TeamOwner = (Get-TeamUser -GroupId $Team | Where-object {$_.Role -eq 'Owner'}).User

Write-Host 7 Doing teamReport bit...
$TeamReport = $TeamReport + [PSCustomObject]@{TeamName = $TeamName;TeamOwners = $TeamOwner -join ', ';}
}

$Path = 'C:\users\USERNAME\TeamOwnerReport'

$TeamReport | Export-csv ("$Path\TeamsReport_" + (get-date -format "dd-MM-yy") +".csv") -NoTypeInformation
```

Any support here would be greatly appreciated - still very much learning the ropes of PowerShell and of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error *Get-Team : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'GroupId'.*, you may have an older version of the MicrosoftTeamsPowerShell module, but then you could try this instead:

```
Import-Module Microsoftteams

Connect-MicrosoftTeams

# read the array of team group id's, remove empty or whitespace only lines
$TeamList   = Get-Content -Path 'C:\users\USERNAME\TeamOwnerReport\List.txt' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }
$TeamReport = Get-Team | Where-object {$TeamList -contains $_.GroupId} | ForEach-Object {
    $owners= Get-TeamUser -GroupId $_.GroupId -Role Owner
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        TeamName   = $_.DisplayName
        TeamOwners = ($owners.User -join ', ')
    }
}


# save the report as CSV file
$outputPath = 'C:\users\USERNAME\TeamOwnerReport_{0:dd-MM-yyyy}.csv' -f (Get-Date)
$TeamReport | Export-Csv -Path $outputPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi again, Theo. Thank you for your input. Whilst the code above appears to be quicker than my original code (takes around 1min 30secs to run) - The .csv that it returns is missing the 'Owners', infact it looks like this:

`"TeamName","TeamOwners"
"STH-GRP-TeamsTestingDemo",""`

Comment: Annnnd on further inspection - our MicrosoftTeamsPoerShell module looks to be version 0.9.5 - Ouch. I'll have to see if we can get this updated to the latest 4.x version. I believe anything older will be unsupported come June/July.

Comment: @DanG Please see my update. It should now also report the owners

Comment: Hi Theo, good news - that seems to be working fantastically! For around 20 teams with around 100 users it returned the data in 2 minutes. A vast improvement - thank you. Now to understand your code and ask the Admin to update the module.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `Get-Team` which, without parameters, will return all teams. This means you're getting the full Team list *every iteration*. You could improve that by changing the query to just a parameter.

```
Write-Host 2 Stepping Through Team GroupIDs...
$TeamIDs = Foreach ($Item in $TeamList)
{get-team -GroupId $Item
}
```

The same thing could be improved on step 5

```
Foreach ($Team in $AllTeams)
{
Write-Host 5 Doing teamName bit...
$TeamName = (Get-Team -GroupId $Team).DisplayName
...
```

But these changes are only to keep your steps the same. This whole script could definitely be improved because you should only need to call `Get-Team` one time per team.

Comment: Thank you, Joel. I wouldn't be lying if i told you i started learning PowerShell yesterday afternoon - your comments are very welcome. I am not precious about the whole script, it is very much a Frankenstein's monster. However, I wouldn't know how to improve upon it atm - again, still learning. Adding the changes as you described now.

Comment: Appears to be returning the error: 
`Get-Team : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'GroupId'.
At C:\Users\gregorydaadmin\TeamOwnerReport\MSTeamOwner.ps1:15 char:11
+ {get-team -GroupId $Item`

Comment: I assumed this was the Microsoft Teams PowerShell function, Get-Team. Is it not? Here's the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/get-team?view=teams-ps