# PowerShell - List items on own line

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

Good afternoon all,

I was very kindly shown the following code by the user 'Theo', the code is designed to return MS Teams Owners and members with their respective team names and Group IDs.

```
    Import-Module Microsoftteams
    Connect-MicrosoftTeams
    
    #=========================================================================
    
    $GUIDList = 'C:\users\Your_User_Name_Here\TeamOwnerReport\ListGUID.txt'
    
    #=========================================================================
    
    $TeamList   = Get-Content -Path "$GUIDList" | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }
    
    $TeamReport = Get-Team | Where-object {$TeamList -contains $_.GroupId} | ForEach-Object {
        $owners= Get-TeamUser -GroupId $_.GroupId -Role Owner
        $members= Get-TeamUser -GroupId $_.GroupID -Role Member
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            TeamName   = $_.DisplayName
            GUID = $_.GroupID
            TeamOwners = ($owners.User -join '; ')
            TeamMembers = ($members.User -join '; ')
        }
    }
    
    #=========================================================================
    
    $FileName = 'MSTeamOwnMem'
    $path = 'C:\Users\Your_User_Name_Here\TeamOwnerReport'
    
    #=========================================================================
    
    $OutputPath = "$path\$FileName-{0:yyyy-MM-dd-HHmm}.csv" -f (Get-Date)
    
    $TeamReport | Export-Csv -Path $OutputPath -NoTypeInformation
    
    Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams
```

This produces a lovely .csv table as below.

| TeamName | GroupID | TeamOwners | TeamMembers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Team1 | GUID1 | Owner1@nhs.net; Owner2@nhs.net | Mem1@nhs.net; Mem2@nhs.net |
| Team2 | GUID2 | Owner3@nhs.net; Owner4nhs.net | Mem3@nhs.net |

I would like the code to instead produce a .csv table that looks as follows

| TeamName | GroupID | UserName | Role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Team1 | GUID1 | Owner1@nhs.net | Owner |
| Team1 | GUID1 | Owner2@nhs.net | Owner |

I have tried removing the `-join` command from the code, but holding my hands up here, I'm unfamiliar with the syntax involved with PowerShell.

Here is the original post with code: [PowerShell Team Owners and Team names from a List of GroupIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72058588/powershell-team-owners-and-team-names-from-a-list-of-groupids)

Any pointers would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, it's just with a quick look at your code, but basically at the moment it's just looping one time, over the list of teams themselves. You want to add more loops, to go through each of the owners and then each of the members. Try replace:

```
    $TeamReport = Get-Team | Where-object {$TeamList -contains $_.GroupId} | ForEach-Object {
        $owners= Get-TeamUser -GroupId $_.GroupId -Role Owner
        $members= Get-TeamUser -GroupId $_.GroupID -Role Member
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            TeamName   = $_.DisplayName
            GUID = $_.GroupID
            TeamOwners = ($owners.User -join '; ')
            TeamMembers = ($members.User -join '; ')
        }
    }
```

with this:

this:

```
    $TeamReport = @()
    $teams = Get-Team | Where-object {$TeamList -contains $_.GroupId}

    foreach ($team in $teams) {
        $owners = Get-TeamUser -GroupId $team.GroupId -Role Owner
        $members = Get-TeamUser -GroupId $team.GroupID -Role Member

        foreach ($owner in $owners) {
            $TeamReport += [PsCustomObject]@{
                TeamName = $team.DisplayName
                GUID = $team.GroupID
                UserName = $owner.User
                Role = 'Owner'
            }
        }

        foreach ($member in $members) {
            $TeamReport += [PsCustomObject]@{
                TeamName = $team.DisplayName
                GUID = $team.GroupID
                UserName = $member.User
                Role = 'Member'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works an absolute charm. Thank you so very much. Your comments help to explain the goings on in the original code and im starting to see why your revised code gives the desired output.

Comment: sure thing - glad to help!